# KeyError: 'collectstatic' When deploying the Django application to pythonanywhere

Tags: django, pythonanywhere

During the implementation of my Django application on pythonanywhere for the first time I encountered such an error. Previous applications with a very similar structure were able to be implemented without any problem

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ebluedesign/.virtualenvs/ebluedesign.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 204, in fetch_command
    app_name = commands[subcommand]
KeyError: 'collectstatic'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ebluedesign/ebluedesign.pythonanywhere.com/manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/ebluedesign/.virtualenvs/ebluedesign.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_comman
d_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/ebluedesign/.virtualenvs/ebluedesign.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/ebluedesign/.virtualenvs/ebluedesign.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 211, in fetch_command
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/home/ebluedesign/.virtualenvs/ebluedesign.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/ebluedesign/.virtualenvs/ebluedesign.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 66, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/ebluedesign/.virtualenvs/ebluedesign.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 157, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/home/ebluedesign/.virtualenvs/ebluedesign.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 985, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 697, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/ebluedesign/ebluedesign.pythonanywhere.com/app_rama/settings.py", line 14, in <module>
    from decouple import config
ImportError: No module named 'decouple'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ebluedesign/.local/bin/pa_autoconfigure_django.py", line 52, in <module>
    main(arguments['<git-repo-url>'], arguments['--domain'], arguments['--python'], nuke=arguments.get('--nuke'))
  File "/home/ebluedesign/.local/bin/pa_autoconfigure_django.py", line 42, in main
    project.run_collectstatic()
  File "/home/ebluedesign/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pythonanywhere/django_project.py", line 87, in run_collectstatic
    '--noinput',
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 291, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/home/ebluedesign/.virtualenvs/ebluedesign.pythonanywhere.com/bin/python', '/home/ebluedesign/ebluedesign.pythonanywhere.com/
manage.py', 'collectstatic', '--noinput']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

The settings file of my application looks like this.

```
import os
from decouple import config

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '********4roco73r7-*********************************'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app',
    'crispy_forms',
    'tinymce',
    'ckeditor',
    'storages',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'app_rama.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'app_rama.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

# STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'app/media')

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

# #<-------------Amazon3S --------->
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'app/static'),
]

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = config('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = config('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'name_one'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}

AWS_LOCATION = 'static'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
STATIC_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_LOCATION)

AWS_PUBLIC_MEDIA_LOCATION = 'media/public'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'mysite.storage_backends.PublicMediaStorage'

AWS_PRIVATE_MEDIA_LOCATION = 'media/private'
PRIVATE_FILE_STORAGE = 'mysite.storage_backends.PrivateMediaStorage'
# #<-------------Amazon3S End -------------->
```

How to solve it? I was looking for other answers on the internet but to no avail.

**requirements.txt**

```
-f /usr/share/pip-wheels
absl-py==0.4.0
aggdraw==1.1.post20051010
alabaster==0.7.11
alembic==1.0.0
aniso8601==3.0.2
ansible==2.6.1
appdirs==1.4.3
argh==0.26.2
arrow==0.12.1
asn1crypto==0.24.0
astor==0.7.1
astropy==2.0.7
async==0.6.2
atomicwrites==1.1.5
attrs==18.1.0
Augustus==0.5.3.0
Automat==0.7.0
Babel==2.6.0
backports-abc==0.5
backports.functools-lru-cache==1.5
backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.5.0.1
backports.weakref==1.0.post1
banal==0.3.7
basemap==1.0.7
bashplotlib==0.6.5
bcrypt==3.1.4
beanstalkc==0.4.0
BeautifulSoup==3.2.1
beautifulsoup4==4.6.0
biopython==1.72
bleach==2.1.3
blessings==1.7
blinker==1.4
bokeh==0.13.0
boto==2.49.0
boto3==1.7.83
botocore==1.10.83
bottle==0.12.13
bottlenose==1.1.8
bpython==0.17.1
BTrees==4.5.0
bz2file==0.98
bzr==2.7.0
cachetools==2.1.0
cairocffi==0.8.1
CairoSVG==1.0.22
census==0.8.7
certifi==2018.8.13
cffi==1.11.5
cftime==1.0.1
Chameleon==3.4
chardet==3.0.4
Cheetah==2.4.4
cheroot==6.4.0
CherryPy==17.0.0
click==6.7
click-plugins==1.0.3
cligj==0.4.0
colorama==0.3.9
colorlog==3.1.4
configobj==5.0.6
configparser==3.5.0
confusable-homoglyphs==3.1.1
constantly==15.1.0
CoolProp==6.1.0
coverage==4.5.1
cryptography==2.2.2
cssselect==1.0.3
cssselect2==0.2.1
curtsies==0.3.0
cycler==0.10.0
cypari==2.3.0
Cython==0.28.4
dataset==1.1.0
decorator==4.3.0
dectate==0.13
defusedxml==0.5.0
Django==1.11.15
django-appconf==1.0.3
django-blog-zinnia==0.20
django-bootstrap-form==3.4
django-classy-tags==0.8.0
django-cms==3.5.2
django-contrib-comments==1.8.0
django-formtools==2.1
django-js-asset==1.1.0
django-mptt==0.9.0
django-object-tools==1.11.0
django-openid-auth==0.14
django-registration==2.4.1
django-sekizai==0.10.0
django-social-auth==0.7.28
django-staticfiles==1.2.1
django-tagging==0.4.6
django-treebeard==4.3
django-xmlrpc==0.1.8
django4facebook==0.1.0
djangocms-admin-style==1.2.8
docopt==0.6.2
docutils==0.14
dominate==2.3.1
dropbox==9.0.0
dulwich==0.19.5
easydev==0.9.37
EasyProcess==0.2.3
elaphe==0.6.0
entrypoints==0.2.3
enum34==1.1.6
epydoc==3.0.1
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
evernote==1.25.3
fabric==2.2.0
facebook-sdk==2.0.0
falcon==1.4.1
feedgenerator==1.9
feedparser==5.2.1
filebrowser-safe==0.5.0
Fiona==1.7.13
Flask==1.0.2
Flask-Admin==1.5.1
Flask-Babel==0.11.2
Flask-Bcrypt==0.7.1
Flask-Bootstrap==3.3.7.1
Flask-HTTPAuth==3.2.4
Flask-Login==0.4.1
Flask-Mail==0.9.1
Flask-OpenID==1.2.5
Flask-RESTful==0.3.6
Flask-Script==2.0.6
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2
Flask-SSLify==0.1.5
Flask-WhooshAlchemy==0.56
Flask-WTF==0.14.2
funcsigs==1.0.2
functools32==3.2.3.post2
future==0.16.0
futures==3.2.0
FXrays==1.3.3
gast==0.2.0
GDAL==1.11.2
gdata==2.0.18
Genshi==0.7
gensim==3.5.0
geographiclib==1.49
GeoIP==1.3.2
geopy==1.15.0
gevent==1.3.5
geventhttpclient==1.3.1
gitdb==0.6.4
gitdb2==2.0.4
GitPython==2.1.11
gmpy==1.17
google-api-python-client==1.7.4
google-auth==1.5.1
google-auth-httplib2==0.0.3
grappelli-safe==0.5.0
greenlet==0.4.13
grequests==0.3.0
grok==1.14.1
grokcore.annotation==1.5.1
grokcore.catalog==2.2.1
grokcore.chameleon==1.0.4
grokcore.component==2.7
grokcore.content==1.3.1
grokcore.formlib==1.11
grokcore.json==1.2.1
grokcore.layout==1.6.1
grokcore.message==0.4.3
grokcore.rest==1.3
grokcore.security==1.6.3
grokcore.site==1.7.1
grokcore.traverser==1.2.1
grokcore.view==2.11
grokcore.viewlet==1.11
grokcore.xmlrpc==1.2.1
grpcio==1.14.1
h5py==2.8.0
hg-git==0.8.11
html5lib==1.0.1
http-parser==0.8.3
httplib2==0.11.3
hupper==1.3
hyperlink==18.0.0
idna==2.7
imagesize==1.0.0
IMAPClient==2.0.0
importscan==0.1
incf.countryutils==1.0
incremental==17.5.0
inflection==0.3.1
invoke==1.1.1
iotop==0.6
ipaddress==1.0.22
ipykernel==4.8.2
ipyparallel==5.0.1
ipython==4.1.2
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipywidgets==5.2.2
isodate==0.6.0
isort==4.3.4
itsdangerous==0.24
jaraco.functools==1.20
jdcal==1.4
jellyfish==0.5.6
Jinja2==2.10
jmespath==0.9.3
jsonschema==2.6.0
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==4.3.0
jupyter-console==5.0.0
jupyter-core==4.4.0
Keras==2.2.2
Keras-Applications==1.0.4
Keras-Preprocessing==1.0.2
kiwisolver==1.0.1
la==0.6.0
linecache2==1.0.0
Logbook==1.4.0
lxml==4.2.3
Mako==1.0.7
marisa-trie==0.7.5
Markdown==2.6.11
MarkupSafe==1.0
martian==1.2
matplotlib==2.2.2
mechanize==0.3.6
mercurial==4.6.2
Mezzanine==4.3.0
mimerender==0.6.0
mistune==0.8.3
mlpy==3.5.0
mock==2.0.0
mod-pywebsocket==0.7.9
moin==1.9.9
more-itertools==4.2.0
morepath==0.18.1
mots-vides==2015.5.11
mplh5canvas==0.7
mpmath==1.0.0
munch==2.3.2
mysql-connector-python==1.0.12
mysqlclient==1.3.13
nbconvert==5.3.1
nbformat==4.4.0
ndg-httpsclient==0.5.0
neo4j-driver==1.6.1
neotime==1.0.0
netCDF4==1.4.0
netifaces==0.10.7
networkx==2.1
nltk==3.3
normality==0.6.1
nose==1.3.7
notebook==4.2.2
numexpr==2.6.5
numpy==1.14.5
oauth==1.0.1
oauth2==1.9.0.post1
oauth2client==4.1.2
oauthlib==2.1.0
opencv-contrib-python-headless==3.4.2.17
openopt==0.5628
openpyxl==2.5.4
Orange==2.7.8
Orange-Text==1.2a1
ordereddict==1.1
oursql==0.9.3.2
packaging==17.1
pandas==0.23.3
pandocfilters==1.4.2
paramiko==2.4.1
parsel==1.5.0
Paste==2.0.3
PasteDeploy==1.5.2
pathlib2==2.3.2
pathtools==0.1.2
patsy==0.5.0
Pattern==2.6
pbr==4.1.0
pdflatex==0.1.0
pdfminer==20140328
pdfrw==0.4
peewee==2.1.2
pelican==3.7.1
pep8==1.7.1
persistent==4.2.4.2
pexpect==4.6.0
pickleshare==0.7.4
Pillow==5.2.0
Pinax==0.9a2
Pint==0.8.1
pisa==3.0.33
Pivy==0.5.0
plaster==1.0
plaster-pastedeploy==0.6
plink==2.2
plotly==3.0.0
pluggy==0.7.1
ply==3.7
pocketsphinx==0.1.15
portend==2.3
pp==1.6.5
praw==6.0.0
prawcore==1.0.0
prettytable==0.7.2
prompt-toolkit==1.0.15
protobuf==3.6.1
psutil==5.4.6
psycopg2-binary==2.7.5
ptyprocess==0.6.0
pudb==2018.1
py==1.5.4
py-bcrypt==0.4
py2neo==4.0.0
PyAMF==0.8.0
pyasn1==0.4.3
pyasn1-modules==0.2.2
PyChart==1.39
pycollada==0.4
pycparser==2.18
pycrypto==2.6.1
pycsp==0.9.2
pycurl==7.43.0.2
pyDatalog==0.17.1
PyDispatcher==2.0.5
pydot==1.2.4
pydub==0.22.1
pyenchant==2.0.0
pyfits==3.5
pyflakes==2.0.0
pygal==2.4.0
pygeoip==0.3.2
Pygments==2.2.0
pygraphviz==1.3.1
pyhdf==0.8.3
PyJWT==1.6.4
Pykka==1.2.1
pymc==2.3.6
pymongo==3.7.1
PyNaCl==1.2.1
pyodbc==4.0.23
pyOpenSSL==18.0.0
pyparsing==2.2.0
PyPDF2==1.26.0
pypdfocr==0.9.1
pypdftk==0.3
Pyphen==0.9.4
pypng==0.0.18
pyproj==1.9.5.1
pyquery==1.4.0
pyramid==1.9.2
PySAL==1.14.3
pyserial==3.4
PySocks==1.6.8
pyspotify==2.0.5
Pyste==0.9.10
PyStemmer==1.3.0
pytesseract==0.2.2
pytest==3.7.1
python-amazon-simple-product-api==2.1.0
python-dateutil==2.7.3
python-decouple==3.1
python-editor==1.0.3
python-gflags==3.1.2
python-inotify==0.5
python-instagram==1.3.2
python-ldap==2.4.25
python-Levenshtein==0.12.0
python-magic==0.4.15
python-mcrypt==1.1
python-mhash==1.4
python-mimeparse==1.6.0
python-openid==2.2.5
python-slugify==1.2.5
pytz==2018.5
PyVirtualDisplay==0.2.1
PyYAML==3.13
pyzmq==17.1.0
qrcode==6.0
qtconsole==4.4.1
Quandl==3.4.0
quantlib==0.1
QuantLib-Python==1.7
queuelib==1.5.0
rdflib==4.2.2
redis==2.10.6
reg==0.11
regex==2018.8.17
remix==2.4.0
reportlab==3.5.0
repoze.lru==0.7
requests==2.19.1
requests-cache==0.4.13
requests-oauthlib==1.0.0
resolver-test==1.4
restkit==4.2.2
RestrictedPython==3.6.0
retrying==1.3.3
rpy2==2.8.6
rsa==3.4.2
ruffus==2.7.0
s3cmd==2.0.2
s3transfer==0.1.13
scandir==1.7
scikit-learn==0.19.2
scikits.statsmodels==0.3.1
scipy==1.1.0
Scrapy==1.5.1
selenium==2.53.6
service-identity==17.0.0
setproctitle==1.1.10
Shapely==1.6.4.post1
simplegeneric==0.8.1
SimpleHMMER==0.2.3
simplejson==3.16.0
simpy==3.0.11
singledispatch==3.4.0.3
six==1.11.0
smart-open==1.6.0
smmap==0.9.0
smmap2==2.0.4
snappy==2.6
snappy-manifolds==1.0
snowballstemmer==1.2.1
soaplib==1.0.0
socketpool==0.5.3
sockjs-tornado==1.0.3
sortedcontainers==2.0.4
South==1.0.2
SPARQLWrapper==1.8.2
speaklater==1.3
spectrum==0.7.3
spherogram==1.8
Sphinx==1.7.6
sphinxcontrib-websupport==1.1.0
splinter==0.7.3
SQLAlchemy==1.2.10
sqlalchemy-migrate==0.11.0
sqlparse==0.2.4
statsmodels==0.9.0
stevedore==1.28.0
stripe==2.0.1
subprocess32==3.5.2
suds==0.4
svn==0.3.46
sympy==1.2
TA-Lib==0.4.17
tables==3.4.4
tabulate==0.8.2
Tempita==0.5.2
tempora==1.13
tensorboard==1.10.0
tensorflow==1.10.0
termcolor==1.1.0
terminado==0.8.1
testpath==0.3.1
texcaller==0
textblob==0.15.1
tinycss==0.4
tinycss2==0.6.1
TornadIO2==0.0.3
tornado==4.5.3
Trac==1.2.2
traceback2==1.4.0
traitlets==4.3.2
transaction==2.2.1
translationstring==1.3
tweepy==3.6.0
twilio==6.15.0
Twisted==17.9.0
twitter==1.18.0
typing==3.6.4
tzlocal==1.5.1
uncertainties==3.0.2
Unidecode==1.0.22
unittest2==1.1.0
update-checker==0.16
uritemplate==3.0.0
urllib3==1.23
urwid==2.0.1
us==1.0.0
venusian==1.1.0
virtualenv==16.0.0
virtualenv-clone==0.3.0
virtualenvwrapper==4.8.2
visitor==0.1.3
VTK==5.10.1
w3lib==1.19.0
waitress==1.1.0
Wand==0.4.4
watchdog==0.8.3
wcwidth==0.1.7
WeasyPrint==0.42.3
web.py==0.39
webapp2==2.5.2
webencodings==0.5.1
WebOb==1.8.2
WebTest==2.0.30
Werkzeug==0.14.1
wheezy.caching==0.1.114
wheezy.core==0.1.140
wheezy.html==0.1.147
wheezy.http==0.1.344
wheezy.routing==0.1.157
wheezy.security==0.1.64
wheezy.template==0.1.167
wheezy.validation==0.1.135
wheezy.web==0.1.485
Whoosh==2.7.4
widgetsnbextension==1.2.6
WTForms==2.2.1
wxPython==3.0.2.0
wxPython-common==3.0.2.0
xgboost==0.72.1
xlrd==1.1.0
xlutils==2.0.0
xlwt==1.3.0
z3c.autoinclude==0.3.6
z3c.flashmessage==1.3
z3c.pt==2.2.3
zbar==0.10
zc.buildout==2.5.2
zc.catalog==1.6
zc.lockfile==1.2.1
ZConfig==3.2.0
zdaemon==4.2.0
ZEO==4.2.1
ZODB==4.4.2
ZODB3==3.11.0
zodbpickle==0.6.0
zope.annotation==4.4.1
zope.app.appsetup==4.0.0a1
zope.app.publication==4.0.0a1.dev0
zope.app.wsgi==4.0.0a4
zope.authentication==4.2.1
zope.browser==2.1.0
zope.browserpage==4.1.0
zope.browserresource==4.1.0
zope.catalog==4.1.0
zope.component==4.2.2
zope.configuration==4.0.3
zope.container==4.1.0
zope.contentprovider==4.0.0
zope.contenttype==4.1.0
zope.datetime==4.1.0
zope.deprecation==4.1.2
zope.dottedname==4.1.0
zope.error==4.3.0
zope.errorview==0.11
zope.event==4.2.0
zope.exceptions==4.0.8
zope.filerepresentation==4.1.0
zope.formlib==4.3.0
zope.generations==3.7.1
zope.i18n==4.1.0
zope.i18nmessageid==4.0.3
zope.index==4.2.0
zope.interface==4.2.0
zope.intid==4.1.0
zope.keyreference==4.1.0
zope.lifecycleevent==4.1.0
zope.location==4.0.3
zope.login==2.0.0
zope.minmax==2.1.0
zope.pagetemplate==4.2.1
zope.password==4.2.0
zope.principalregistry==4.0.0
zope.processlifetime==2.1.0
zope.proxy==4.2.0
zope.ptresource==4.0.0
zope.publisher==4.3.0
zope.schema==4.4.2
zope.security==4.0.3
zope.securitypolicy==4.0.0
zope.session==4.1.0
zope.site==4.0.0
zope.size==4.1.0
zope.tal==4.2.0
zope.tales==4.1.1
zope.testbrowser==4.0.4
zope.testing==4.5.0
zope.traversing==4.0.0
zope.viewlet==4.0.0
```

Comment: what's "decouple"? A pip package?

Comment: Environment variables, adding them according to this tutorial https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/2015/11/26/package-of-the-week-python-decouple.html  (until now it worked properly).

Comment: then probably python-decouple isn't installed in your virtualenv. Make sure to tell pythonanywhere to install it first.

Comment: Please show your requirements.txt.

Comment: I added above. I try also ' pip install django-staticfiles ' but does not work.

Comment: Your `requiremants.txt` look like a result of `pip freeze` in the PythonAnywhere bash console outside of your virtual environment. How does `pip freeze` look inside of your venv?

Answer (score 2):

Have you installed all the packages in requirements.txt? If not install it in a virtualenv using the command

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

It seems like 'decouple' is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered exactly this issue and ensured that my virtualenv had all the correct  packages required.

My issue was that the scheduled task wasn't using my virtualenv. Originally I used:
    `/home/myusername/myproject/mytask.py`

And to use run the scheduled task in the virtualenv:
`/home/myusername/.virtualenvs/myvenv/bin/python /home/myusername/myproject/mytask.py`

More information on this can be found here: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/VirtualEnvInScheduledTasks

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter this error, just delete the following code from inside the settings.py

from types import _StaticFunctionType